# Ceiling Fan with 2 Switches and Remote

Tags: ceiling-fan

I just recently bought a the merwry ceiling fan from home depot.  It's a wireless fan with remote and I have 2 switches in my house, 1 with light dimmer.

I wired everything up and everything seems to work with both switches.  Is there any way to wire the ceiling fan so that both switches work and also the remote works for both light and fan?

Right now, I can control the ceiling fan with both switch and remote but I can only control the light with the switch and not with the remote.

Comment: Please post the model # of the fan.

Comment: Is the remote supposed to control the light also? If so, the switches have nothing to do with the way the remote works, unless both switches are off. This means no power to the fan, therefore no remote functions. Like posted above, what the model number or a link to the fan?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do that with those cheapies.  Use of the remote is vital to reducing the cost.

Literally no way.  I do some exotic things with electrical, but nope.

You bought it for the savings, enjoy them, don't look back.  No regrets!